# Monotouch Importing Contact - Return Type Issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to have this method return a person if they are selected. My problem is that I get an error saying that the delegate cannot return a type other than `void` which is annoying because I don't want this method to return unless one of those two actions have happened. Any suggestions?

```
public static ABPerson ImportContact ()
        {
            // Create placeholder for contact
            ABPeoplePickerNavigationController _contactController = new ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ();
            AppDelegate.navigation.PresentViewController (_contactController, true, null);

            _contactController.Cancelled += delegate {
                AppDelegate.navigation.DismissViewController (true, null);
                return;
            };

            _contactController.SelectPerson += delegate(object sender, ABPeoplePickerSelectPersonEventArgs e) {
                _importedContact = e.Person.GetEmails().FirstOrDefault;
                AppDelegate.navigation.DismissViewController (true, delegate {
                    return e.Person;
                });
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return function result in inner delegate method. It's not possible to implement. Try to use public event instead. I. e.:

```cs
    public event Action<ABPerson> OnPersonSelect;
    public void ImportContact ()
    {
        // Create placeholder for contact
        ABPeoplePickerNavigationController _contactController = new ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ();
        NavigationController.PresentViewController (_contactController, true, null);

        _contactController.Cancelled += delegate {
            NavigationController.DismissViewController (true, null);
            return;
        };

        _contactController.SelectPerson += delegate(object sender, ABPeoplePickerSelectPersonEventArgs e) {
            var _importedContact = e.Person;
            NavigationController.DismissViewController (true, delegate {
                if (OnPersonSelect != null)
                {
                    OnPersonSelect(_importedContact);
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

Note that I mark this method as non-static to use it in my own test sample.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would recommend to people to use `PushViewController (view, animated)` instead of present like above in my example and @Maxim Korobov's as well. Dismiss using `PopViewControllerAnimated (animated)`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve it:

```
        private static void ImportContact ()
        {
            if (_contactController == null)
                _contactController = new ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ();
            AppDelegate.navigation.PresentViewController (_contactController, true, null);

            _contactController.Cancelled += delegate {
                if (!AppDelegate.navigation.PresentedViewController.IsBeingPresented)
                    AppDelegate.navigation.DismissViewController (true, null);
                return;
            };

            _contactController.SelectPerson += delegate(object sender, ABPeoplePickerSelectPersonEventArgs e) {
                if (!AppDelegate.navigation.PresentedViewController.IsBeingPresented) {
                    AppDelegate.navigation.DismissViewController (true, delegate { 
                        MapImportedContact (e.Person);
                    });
                }
                return;
            };
        }
```

After I map the fields from that, I called a method

```
PopulateClientFields (Client mappedClient)
```

That method sets all of the `EntryElements` to the value passed in and then reloaded the view with:

```
clientsView.ReloadData ();
```

Worked like a charm. Sorry I didn't actually post this sooner.